# CodeDom Reference VB6 dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, codedom

I have had no problems adding .dll files (generated from Visual Studio) to a CodeDom generated executable file. To do so, I have been using the following code:

**Code:**

```
string[] referenceAssemblies = { 
                                            "System.dll", 
                                            "System.Windows.Forms.dll", 
                                            "System.Drawing.dll", 
                                            "System.Data.dll",
                                            "System.Xml.dll"
                                           };

            // Add the referenced assemblies to the compiler parameteres
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies, exeFile, false);
```

However, I would now like to add a Visual Basic 6 made .dll file as a reference to a CodeDom generated executable file. I do ***NOT***, however want to add this .dll file as an embedded file. I want the .dll file to be the equivalent to doing the following in Visual Studio:

**From Visual Studio:**

1. Open Visual Studio > New windows forms application
2. References > Add Reference > Com Reference
3. Call a function named 'Test(foo as string)' using the following

**code:**

```
Project1.Class1 vb6Test = new Project1.Class1();
                vb6Test.Test("Some String");
```

**From Visual Basic 6:**

1. New Project > Properties > Active X Dll
2. Create new Class Module with Public modifiers and add in the following function:
3. Create Project1.dll

**Code:**

```
public Function Test(foo as String)
    MsgBox(foo)
End Function
```

Now, from Visual Studio I am able to add Project1.dll as a reference to my winform application and call it using the code above (in the Visual Studio section). I want to incorporate the ***exact same functionalitiy*** through the use of CodeDom. However, I am encountering a CodeDom error during code generation:

**CodeDom code - Including the .dll file as a referenced assembly:**

```
string[] referenceAssemblies = { 
                                            "System.dll", 
                                            "System.Windows.Forms.dll", 
                                            "System.Drawing.dll", 
                                            "System.Data.dll",
                                            "System.Xml.dll",
                                            @"C:\Users\EVAN\Desktop\file.dll"
                                           };
```

**Error:**

> Metadata file 'c:\Users\EVAN\Desktop\file.dll' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '

I have no idea what the problem could be as Visual Studio has no problem loading it as a reference, when I do it manually.

I can't wait to hear what you all have to say!

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: The vb6 dll first needs to be converted to an interop library with the Tlbimp.exe tool.  You then add *that* DLL to the references.

Comment: Since you posted this about a half ago, I have been doing my research. It seems like Tlbimp is a built-in function. Could you by any chance offer an example of how to use this from my application? Will all of my application's users be able to utilize this feature?

I have been using this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/693cawes.aspx