# CodeDom Reference ActiveX Resource

Tags: c#, com, activex, codedom

**Very Similar Unanswered Question Here: [CodeDom Reference VB6 dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667095/codedom-reference-vb6-dll)**

I've been searching google for the last few days regarding an issue referencing an ActiveX/COM assembly using an in-memory assembly compiled using CodeDom (Visual Basic Provider).

I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to do and, sorry ahead of time if the technical lingo is off!

**Visual Studio Process - Working!**

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Create new Windows Forms project (C#).
3. Right-click References -> Add Reference...
4. Select the Executable I want (Executable may be important here?)
5. The operation generates two references.
6. These classes, methods, etc. become available for us as I want.

**CodeDom - Not working!**

Pre-Work Steps Taken!

1. Used TibImp.exe on the Executable to generate the two .dll files (Interop).
2. Moved the generated .dll files to an accessible location (Desktop!)

CodeDom Code Example

```
                string sCodeLocation = @"C:\Interop\Code.vb";
                string[] sCodeContents = { File.ReadAllText(sCodeLocation) };


                List<string> ReferenceList = new List<string>();

                ReferenceList.Add("System.dll");
                ReferenceList.Add(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Interops\CustomActiveX.dll");

                string[] References = ReferenceList.ToArray();

                CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
                CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
                CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
                CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize /platform:x86";
                CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(References);

                VBCodeProvider Provider = new VBCodeProvider();
                CompilerResults CompileResult = Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, sCodeContents);
```

**The Exception I'm Receiving**
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CustomActiveX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

**List Of Attempted Resolutions (Based on Google Searches)**

- Ensure platform is set across the board (x86 in this case).
- Use TibImp.exe to create Interop DLL's.
- Tried referencing with CompilerParameters.EmbeddedResources (But don't understand it)
- Tried referencing CompilerParameters.LinkedResources (But don't understand it)

**Possible Workaround (Not tested -- not preferred)**

As a workaround, I thought about maybe having my CodeDom referenced snippet of code load the assembly dynamically on its end. However, if Visual Studio can reference the COM / ActiveX object and use it, I want to make CodeDom do the same.

Comment: A guess is that "**or one of its dependencies.**" is the culprit.  Have you verified that all "CustomActiveX" dependencies are reachable?

Comment: I believe they are, or they should be. Adding the reference via Visual Studio works perfectly fine. I just need a better understanding of what Visual Studio does when a reference is added, that is missing in my CodeDom code. I thought TibImp would do the trick but, it didn't. Now I'm left now knowing what else is missing.